# How to embed Eclipse Intro (introContent.xml...)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rcp, composite

I've finally managed to create a Eclipse RCP -Intro-Page.
The content of the page is managed by the introContent.xml through some css-sheets.
Everytime, when I startup the Eclipse-Application the intro will appear.
The intro looks fine.. - so far so good.
But there is 1 ugly thing: The Intro is embeded in a Tab like the common eclipse-intro:
http://blog.hexagonstar.com/wp-content/uploads/eclipse_intro_screen.jpg

But I like to embed the intro in a swt-composite.
Currently it looks like this:

```
IIntroPart currentIntro = getWorkbench().getIntroManager().showIntro(null, false);
```

Is there a way to embed it into a composite?

Answer (score 0):

The intro manager just shows the introduction as though it were a normal view so I don't think there is any way to do what you want.